# How to include license information for library that imports LGPL licensed library?

Tags: licensing, lgpl, license-notice

I have made a python library that imports an LGPL licensed python library.

My library does not modify the LGPL library, but it cannot operate without the import.

Is my library a "combined work", as defined in the LGPL license?

If it is, then regarding section 4.b of the LGPL license, do I include the GPL and LGPL license documents as text files? Is there a convention for naming these files?

**Edit:** The following post explains the concept of an LGPL combined work: [Looking at the LGPL license](https://bitdepth.thomasrutter.com/2009/01/17/looking-at-the-lgpl-license/) by Thomas Rutter, 17 January 2009.

From my understanding, my library does not qualify as a combined work, because I do not actually modify the LGPL library code, and I do not redistribute it. Is my interpretation correct? In my documentation, I suggest to the users of my library a modification that they can themselves make to the LGPL library to optimize performance. From my understanding, this is still not a combined work, because I do not actually distribute the LGPL library - I assume that the user already has access to it.

I assume likewise that my library is not a combined library.

The first answer to the thread [Using LGPL code for commercial application](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/439136.html)  (December 2004) seems to support my understanding that compliance with the LGPL library is in the distribution of my library. So my library can import the LGPL library, but the LGPL license does not force me to do anything because I do not modify and distribute the LGPL library.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, or let me know if I am right.